# How to set term freq bound to extract a new term doc matrix?

Tags: r, bigdata, sparse-matrix, text-mining, tm

I have a term doc matrix (16,977 terms, 29,414 documents):

```
Non-/sparse entries: 355000/499006478
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 7 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

For further analysis I got to restrict the term number to 2,425. How can I generate a new term doc matrix by including terms with freq over and above 20 for instance?

Since the matrix is large, traditional method `as.matrix` cannot be applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might work... Index the DTM as a simple triplet matrix using a function from the slam package, that'll save you from having to convert it to a dense matrix.

```
library(slam)
library(tm)
data(crude)
dtm1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)


# Find the total occurances of each word in all docs
colTotals <-  col_sums(dtm1)

# keep only  words that occur >20 times in all docs
dtm2 <- dtm1[,which(colTotals > 20)]

> dtm1
A document-term matrix (20 documents, 1266 terms)

Non-/sparse entries: 2255/23065
Sparsity           : 91%
Maximal term length: 17 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

> dtm2
A document-term matrix (20 documents, 12 terms)

Non-/sparse entries: 174/66
Sparsity           : 28%
Maximal term length: 6 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Does that work on your data and answer your question?

Comment: Hey, it did work, quite interested in the mechanisms, why matrix calculation won't do the job, running out of mem., but in triplet matrix it can? Thanks again, have adopted your answer.

Comment: The sparse matrix format (like simple triplet) doesn't store zeros. It just stores non-zero values and their indices (row num, col num) so you could 're-inflate' the matrix if you wanted to

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible with a control list

```
 library(tm)
 dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(your.corpus, control = list(
          bounds=list(global=c(20,Inf))
 ))
 inspect(dtm)
```